# What does question mark equals mean in CoffeeScript?

Tags: syntax, coffeescript, operators

In this line of code of an Backbone app:

```
window.App ?= {}
```

what does `?=` mean? Is is something like initialization of a Backbone app with empty defaults?

I'm new to Backbone/CoffeeScript and I read that an empty app (in CoffeeScript) would look like:

```
window.MyApp =
  Models: {}
  Collections: {}
  Views: {}
  Routers: {}
  initialize: -> 
    #do stuff
```

So is the first a shorthand for the second?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is the [existential operator in CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/#operators) and would be (almost) equivalent to this JS

```
window.App = window.App || {};
```

It ensures that your `App` namespace is defined.